# Error while trying load SQL file into database

Tags: mysql

When I tried to execute:

```
mysql> source \C:\SQlscript\DB_Scripts.sql
```

I am getting the following error:

> Failed to open file 'C:\SQlscript\DB_Scripts.sql', error:
>   2B_Scripts.sql', error: 2

I tried backslash,f orward slash everything, what is the problem here?

Comment: I'd navigate to the directory where that script lives in a command shell and try executing using a relative path in MySQL:

Answer (score 0):

try to lose first slash, one before c:

source C:\SQlscript\DB_Scripts.sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql> source C:/SQlscript/DB_Scripts.sql
```